# React Bootstrap JS file

Tags: reactjs

In react how to add bootstrap JS file ,i installed bootstrap there and it working but for JS isn't working
.
so in my webpage i want to add some dropdown so in that dropdown we need that JS file

after click on it ,it  will be work

Comment: can you see `popperjs` in package.json file ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.